# Java class diagrams for Eclipse? (Galileo 3.52)

Tags: eclipse

I'm a Java/Eclipse noob and I want to generate class diagrams from my source.   I'm unemployed so Free would be a good price.  What are some reasonably stable plugins for Galileo to do this?

BTW, I know the Eclipse project has a UML sub-project.   I couldn't quite tell what state of readiness it was in or whether it could generate class diagrams from my source code.  UML is probably overkill for what I want - it does a LOT more than class diagrams - but I'll take it if it's my best option.

Does anyone have any experience with ObjectAid?  (in their FAQ ObjectAid refers to a commercial version the download looked free so I was a little confused)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you eUml2 (Eclipse UML subproject isn't enough mature yet):

- http://www.soyatec.com/euml2/

I used it last week to do reverse engineering (generate diagram from source), works pretty well and annotation based.

I hate creating this kind of diagram and this tool saved a HUGE amount of time, by creating beautiful diagram from my soure code.

There is a free version ! ... the one I used.

Comment: The Studio (NON-free) is distinguished from the free version saying it can "Mix java and UML within Eclipse. "   So I don't understand what the free version does then.  It doesn't work in Eclipse or it doesn't work with Java?  You generated a class diagram from source, which is all I want, but was that running outside of Eclipse?

Comment: Only limitation I'm aware are advanced features for reverse engineering. With the free version you can even modify your model and reflect change to code. You can install it as eclipse plugin... just give it a try, you will see functionality by yourself !

Comment: I tried to install it and got "Cannot connect to keystore.
  This trust engine is read only.  Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.   Software currently installed: eUML2 Free Edition 3.4.0.20091121 . . .

Comment: ...etc           On the soyatec forum I see 2 other people with this error on Galileo, but they got no responses!                  I installed ObjectAid which installed successfully on the 2nd try and seems to work pretty well so far.                             I'll mark this as "answered" even though I was hoping for more responses.

Comment: So you're accepting an answer that recommends a tool you couldn't get to work? Maybe you should answer your own question with ObjectAid and accept that. FYI there are other SO questions along these lines which got ObjectAid as the answer, though more input would be good.